# Magento 2 How to get customer collection from website id?

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, websites

I want to get collection for customer website wise. I have a website id, and now I want all the customers which belong to that particular website id.

I am trying here:

```
using \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory

$customers = $this->_customerFactory->create();             

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $this->dataHelper->assignLocationToCustomer($location,$customer);           
}
```

How can I get collection website wise?

Comment: what have you tried? just add a filter for website_id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get collection website wise using below code:

```
protected $_customerFactory;

\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory

$this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;


$customers = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                  ->addAttributeToFilter("website_id", array("eq" => $websiteId));              

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    print_r($customer->getData());          
}
```

Comment: I believe this line $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection() without any filter loads all the customers in the database, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory as  CustomerCollection;


            $customerCount = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('website_id', $websiteId);
```